# Set Theory & Geometry: Two arcs on the same circle overlap with wrapping values

Tags: math, set, geometry, computational-geometry

As a background, I'm a computer programmer and I'm working on a software library that allows a computer to quickly search through all dates to find a set of dates that satisfies a criteria.  For example:
I want a list of every possible time that has ever occurred that has occurred on a friday or a saturday that is in April or May during the first week of the month.

My library uses numerical sets to efficiently represent ranges of dates that satisfy a criteria.

I've been thinking about ways to improve the performance of some parts of the app and I think that by combining sets and some geometry, I can really improve my results.  However, my geometry is a bit rusty and I was hoping you might could help.

Here's my thought:

Certain elements of time can be represented as a circular dial.  For example, Minutes can be positioned on a clock with values between 0...59.  We could store valid ranges as a list of arcs.  For example,  If we wanted all times that ended with 05..10, we could store [5,10].  If we wanted all times that end with :45-59 or :00-15, we could store [45, 15].  Notice how this last arc "loops around" the dial.  [Here's a mockup showing different ranges intersecting on a dial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISWIq.png)

My question is this:
Given a set of whole numbers between N...M arranged into a circle.
Given Arc1 which is representing by [A, B] and Arc2 which is represented by [C, D] where A, B, C, and D are all within in range N...M

How do I determine:
A.  Whether the arcs intersect.
B.  If they do, what their intersection is.
C.  If they do, what their union is.

Thank you so much for your help.  If you're not able to help, if you can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: There can be two intersections, if the arcs loop around and overlap at both ends.

Comment: Hints: Arc loops if second number is smaller then first. There are three possibilities: 0, 1, or 2 arcs that loops, each possibility is easy to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and safe approach is to split the intervals that straddle 0. Then you perform pairwise interval intersection/union (for instance `if A < D and C < B then [max(A,C), min(B,D)]` for the intersection), and merge them if they meet at 0.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the primitive operation to implement would be something like 'is the number X contained in the arch [A,B]'.   Once you have that, you could implement an [A,B]/[C,D] arch-intersection predicate by something like -

> Arch intersection means exactly that at least one of the following conditions is met:
>
> 1. C is contained in [A,B]
> 2. D is contained in [A,B]
> 3. A is contained in [C,D]
> 4. B is contained in [C,D]

One way to implement this contained-in-arch test without any branches is with some trigonometry and vector cross product.  Not sure it would be faster (the math/branches performance tradeoff is entirely empiric), but it might be worth a try.

Denote Xa = sin(X/N * 2PI), Ya = cos(X/N * 2PI) and similarly for Xb,Yb etc.

> C is contained in [A,B] is equivalent to:
>
> 1. Xa * Yc - Ya * Xc > 0
>
> *AND*
>
> 2. Xc * Yb - Yc * Xb > 0

You can complete the other 3 conditions in an identical manner.

Hope this turns out useful.